# How to use Apache Beam Direct runner to authenticate with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How to use Apache Beam Direct runner to authenticate with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?
I don't want to authenticate using gcloud account. I have a service account(json) which I set as System variable. How do I have Apache Beam program(running as DirectRunner) authenticate using that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

My usecase would be access GCP Pub/Sub resources in the Apache beam program, so need to authenticate

Answer (score 5):

### Preface

As of today at the current version of the Python SDK 2.9.0 Google cloud PubSub functionality is still actively developed and currently only designed for the streaming processing use only, so you cannot use them as part of your pipeline to publish to PubSub.

You can still install a Google PubSub client but you will stumble upon some limitation and nuances due to specifics of the Apache beam runtime like:

- You will have to install `google-cloud-pubsub` and specify your dependency for Apache beam
- Overcome serialization incompatibility of installed PubSub client for Apache Beam pipeline
- Somehow explicitly provide authentication credentials for the PubSub client

Here is a basic walkthrough to get a pipeline capable to publish elements from a processed collection to Google cloud PubSub service.

Let's assume a basic structure:

```
├── my_stuff
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_package.py
├── .gitignore
├── main.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

#### Get The PubSub Client

Install **google-cloud-pubsub** (assuming pip: `pip install google-cloud-pubsub`) and now you will hit the bump of [providing dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies) and I suggest to follow the last section of the documentation and provide a `setup.py` with some meta-data and your package dependency:

```python
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="my_stuff",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="My Pipeline for DirectRunner that publishes to Google Cloud PubSub",
    long_description=open("README.md").read(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
    ],
    author="John Doe",
    author_email="john.doe@example.com",
    url="https://example.com/",
    license="proprietary",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=True,
    install_requires=['google-cloud-pubsub==0.35.4'],
)
```

*You can use `pip freeze | grep google-cloud-pubsub` to get the exactly installed version.*

### Make PubSub Client Serializable

If you just try to `Map` a publishing function having an instance of the PubSub client then you will get a weird error from Apache Beam saying it cannot unserialize it.
To overcome this you can make a callable class and implement a few methods following the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) to overcome a serialization issue.

Here is a basic example of PubSub publisher instantiating a client:

```python
class Publisher(object):
    """
    PubSub publisher for the beam pipeline.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def init_client():
        return pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials='TODO: Get credentials')

    def __init__(self, topic):
        self.topic = topic
        self.client = self.init_client()

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.topic

    def __setstate__(self, topic):
        self.topic = topic
        self.client = self.init_client()

    def __call__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        self.client.publish(self.topic, b'{}'.format(item))
```

### Specify Credentials

It was not clear from the question there is a need to reuse credentials of the pipeline run-time or needed to be specified separately.
There are few ways to specify credentials. You can construct them using `service_account.Credentials` or reuse credentials from the run-time using `GoogleCredentials`.

#### Hard-coded credentials

```python
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.oauth2 import service_account

client1 = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(
    credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info({
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "****",
        "private_key_id": "****",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n****\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        "client_email": "****",
        "client_id": "****",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/***"
    })
)
```

#### Credentials from JSON file (via OS environment variable)

```python
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import os

client2 = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(
    credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
    )
)
```

#### Reusing run-time credentials (used for pipeline execution)

```python
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

client3 = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(
    credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
)
```

### Usage

Now you can use `Publisher` in your pipeline like any other transformation:

```python
published = (pipeline | "Publish" >> beam.Map(Publisher("pub/sub/topic")))
```

Just don't forget that you will need to add `--setup_file /absolute/path/to/setup.py` argument for the pipeline runner.

Comment: Thanks. I used java, and figured out option to pass-in the credentials

Comment: Pardon, I didn't guess it was a question for the Java SDK. Can you please [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for thus who seeks an answer for the same problem on Java SDK? Or maybe an upvote for my solution for people who got stuck on the same issue using SDK for Python.

Answer (score 0):

When you run locally, your Apache Beam pipeline always runs as the GCP account that you configured with the gcloud command-line tool. You can change the account used by gcloud using [`gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) and then [`gcloud config set`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set).

Note that when you use Java and Maven, you can use the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as detailed in the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven).

And when you use Java and Eclipse, you can also configure it to [use your service account key](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse#configure-execution-options).

Comment: My usecase is not running in Dataflow. I am running as DirectRunner from my local, but would access GCP services(say PubSub). So, I am looking how to authenticate using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. The Quickstart more of looks like for creating a Dataflow pipeline itself.

Comment: Yes, the quickstart is designed for a dataflow pipeline, but I shared it with the only intention to show that with Java and Maven you use the environment variable. Note that you can choose a runner, which in your case would be the direct runner.

Comment: If you set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in your environment variable, your pipeline will use this to authenticate against GCP